# Change languag of text to speech

Tags: python, azure

I want to change the voice of azure from python, with these characteristics

```
languageCode = 'es‑MX'
ssmlGender = 'FEMALE' 
voicName = 'es‑MX‑DaliaNeural'
```

but i'm new to azure so i don't know how, this is my code:

```
import PyPDF2
import azure.cognitiveservices.speech as sdk

key = "fake key"
region = "fake region"

config = sdk.SpeechConfig(subscription=key, region=region)
synthesizer = sdk.SpeechSynthesizer(speech_config=config)

book = open("prueba.pdf", "rb")
reader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(book)

for num in range(0,reader.numPages):
    text = reader.getPage(num).extractText()

result = synthesizer.speak_text_async(text).get()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acording to the documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/how-to-speech-synthesis?tabs=browserjs%2Cterminal&pivots=programming-language-python#select-synthesis-language-and-voice you should be able to do:

```
config.speech_synthesis_language = "es‑MX" 
config.speech_synthesis_voice_name ="es-MX-DaliaNeural"
```

The list of voices is here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/language-support?tabs=tts